# How to postback Action to the chat?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Using  Adaptive Cards in NodeJS for a skype bot.Can we pass the selected option's values of the Input.ChoiceSet using the Action.Submit as plain text to the chat (similar to imback) or is there a way to access the data object of the Action.Submit and access this object to extract the data and pass this (postback) to the chat.

Comment: What language are u using? C# or Node?

Comment: I am using Node.